# Maven help:evaluate output broken on Ubuntu 23.04 (Bash 5.2)

Tags: bash, maven

For quite some time now I have used the following command to programmatically get the artifact version from a Maven project (e.g. for CI/CD purposes):

```sh
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Recently, that command broke.
For whatever reason, something looking like (a fragment of) a shell escaping sequence is now included in the output, not rendered by the shell, but of course breaking any commands using the output.

To illustrate what I mean:

```sh
# What I expect (Ubuntu 22.04, Maven 3.6.3, maven-help-plugin 3.4.0, Bash 5.1.16)
$ mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout | hexdump -C
00000000  31 2e 30 2e 30                                    |1.0.0|
00000005

# What happens now (Ubuntu 23.04, Maven 3.8.7, maven-help-plugin 3.4.0, Bash 5.2.15)
$ mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout | hexdump -C
00000000  31 2e 30 2e 30 1b 5b 30  6d                       |1.0.0.[0m|
00000009

$ mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version --batch-mode -q -DforceStdout | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 30 6d 31 2e 30 2e  30 1b 5b 30 6d           |.[0m1.0.0.[0m|
0000000d
```

---

Naturally, the first thing I assumed was that somehow my shell / environment was messed up, so I recreated the issue in Docker. You can try for yourself to generate the above output.

```docker
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update && apt install -y maven bsdmainutils

WORKDIR /code

RUN cat <<EOF > /code/test.sh
    mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout | hexdump -C
EOF

RUN cat <<EOF > /code/pom.xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
EOF

CMD ["sh", "test.sh"]
```

```docker
FROM ubuntu:23.04

RUN apt update && apt install -y maven bsdmainutils

WORKDIR /code

RUN cat <<EOF > /code/test.sh 
    mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout | hexdump -C 
EOF

RUN cat <<EOF > /code/pom.xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
EOF

CMD ["sh", "test.sh"]
```

---

Am I missing something? Do I have to upgrade my Google-Fu?

If this is indeed a bug, any help towards reporting that (to which project even?) would also be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the Dockerfile. BTW, there is also an official Maven image based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This very much looks like coloured console output.

To avoid this, I added the `--batch-mode` flag in my scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This might be helpful to others, but sadly not in this case. If I add the flag (I've edited the question accordingly), the output actually gets worse, because there is now also garbage in front of the version number.

Comment: I use `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout --batch-mode --errors` to get the version number in Maven 3.8.7, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Interesting. Which OS (+version) and bash version do you use?

Comment: The image `maven:3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-11`

Comment: That works, but it is based on older versions of system libraries (e.g. bash 5.1, libc 2.35 etc.).

Comment: So if you update system libraries on `maven:3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-11`, does it start to break?

Comment: I sadly do not have the expertise to do that. If someone else could help, that'd be awesome though :)
Regardless, I do think that behavior under Ubuntu 23.04 should not happen (or I did something wrong).

Comment: @flonix Yeah, this is strange. It sounds like it would be a good idea to raise a bug ticket for Maven. As a workaround, you could probably just filter out the colour markup stuff with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -Doutput=>(cat) > /dev/null
```

This works by suppressing the normal output from Maven while making it write to a file that is the stdin of the cat command, making it output to stdout without the ANSI color codes. Tested in bash.